# How can I terminate a process and verify its not running anymore in C?

Tags: c, process, signals, terminate, kill-process

I want to fully terminate a process on Linux C89.

The flow is: check if its already dead, if not, let it die peacefully using `sigterm` and wait 10 seconds till it dies. If its still alive - `SIGKILL` it.

```
int TerminateProcessIMP(pid_t process_to_kill)
{    
    assert(process_to_kill);
    
    /*---------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  check if process is already does not exist */
    if (!IsProcessAliveIMP(process_to_kill))
    {
        return (SUCCESS);
    }
    /*---------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  terminate process_to_kill   */
    if (kill(process_to_kill, SIGTERM))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    
    if (!IsProcessAliveIMP(process_to_kill))
    {
        return (SUCCESS);
    }
    
    /*---------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  if its still alive, SIGKILL it */
    if (kill(process_to_kill, SIGKILL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    
    if (!IsProcessAliveIMP(process_to_kill))
    {
        return (SUCCESS);
    }
    /*---------------------------------------------------------*/

    return (FAILURE);
}
/******************************************************************************/
int IsProcessAliveIMP(pid_t process_to_check)
{
    time_t start_time = 0;
    time_t end_time = 0;
    time_t time_to_wait = 10; /* in seconds */
    
    assert(process_to_check);
    
    start_time = time(0);
    end_time = start_time + time_to_wait;
    
    /*  give it time to be terminated because maybe it frees memory meanwhile */
    while (0 != kill(process_to_check, 0) && time(0) < end_time)
    {}
    
    /*  check if it still exists */
    if (0 == kill(process_to_check, 0))
    {
        return (0);
    }
    
    /* the process is still alive */
    return (1);
}
```

What do you think?

Right now, it does not work and does not terminate the process.

It tries to terminate the process but fails to do that. I can't figure out why.

Thanks.

Comment: Which OS, if any? Watchdog is a term referring to a form of hardware reset circuitry in embedded systems.

Comment: @Lundin Hey, the Watchdog is not the major topic here. I'm speaking generally on `how can I terminate a process` and why is my code not working. The watchdog isn't so relevant, I'll delete it from the post to not confuse others, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing unnecessary things.

To check if a process exists:

```
kill(pid, 0);
```

If the return value is 0, then the process exists, if -1 then you have to check `errno`. In case of `ESRCH`:

> The target process or process group does not exist.  Note that an existing process might be a zombie, a process that has terminated execution, but has not yet been wait(2)ed for.

---

To terminate a process:

```
kill(pid, SIGTERM); // signal can be blocked, handled or ignored
```

or

```
kill(pid, SIGKILL); // signal cannot be blocked, handled or ignored
```

After a kill, you have to wait for the process via:

```
waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
```

> If `status` is not `NULL`, `wait()` and `waitpid()` store status information in the `int` to which it points. This integer can be inspected with the macros, described in the man page.

---

See

[man kill](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)
[man waitpid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)

---

**Example:**

```
int TerminateProcessIMP(pid_t pid)
{
    //check if process exists
    int res = kill(pid, 0);
    
    if ((res == -1) && (errno != ESRCH)) {
        //error: either EINVAL or EPERM
        //ESRCH: an existing process might be a zombie
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (res == 0) { //process exists
        
        //ask politely to terminate
        
        if (kill(pid, SIGTERM) == -1) {
            //error: unable to send a signal to the process
            return -1;
        }
        
        //let us see if the child complied to our request
        res = waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
        
        if (res == -1) {
            //most likely not our child (errno == ECHILD)
            //but the process could follow our request and still terminate
            //if you want to be sure goto SIGKILL below
            //or return
        } else if (res == 0) {
           //our child, but at this point the child has not terminated yet 
           //(maybe it will never)
           //either continue to wait or goto SIGKILL below
        } else {
           //child complied to our request and terminated in time
           //res contains the id of the child (res == pid)
           return res;
        }

        //--- or ---

        /* do {
            res = waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
            //because of WNOHANG
            sleep(1);
            //your timeout method goes here
        } while (!res);

        if (res == -1) { //same as above }
        if (res  >  0) { return res;     } */
        
    }
    
    //at this point, the process either does not exists (maybe zombie), 
    //is not our child or refused our request (SIGTERM)
    
    //send a SIGKILL signal to the process
    kill(pid, SIGKILL);
    
    //wait for the process to terminate
    res = waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    
    /*if (res == -1) {
        //not our child, or process does not exists
    }*/
    
    /*if (res > 0) {
        //child successfully terminated
    }*/
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! What about `waitpid(process_to_check, &status, WNOHANG);`  ? What is the difference between that and between the `waitpid(pid, &status, 0` that you suggested?

Comment: About the `ESRCH` , what about killing a zombie process? is it possible? because in my case, i'm trying to kill a process and then restart it. the problem is that even if I kill it, it still stays in the `htop`

Comment: **WNOHANG** return immediately if no child has exited. If you want to be sure, that a child has terminated, don't use it.

Comment: wait, wait, wait ... waitpid kills that zombie.

Comment: I actually wanted to `wait` in the `busy wait` as you can see in my `while loop`. a bad idea I guess. Can you add on `waitpid(pid, &status, 0);` ? I thought it also returns immediately if no child has exited.. so I see no difference between that and `WHOHANG`

Comment: Read the man page. `waitpid` blocks, until that child has terminated, unless `WNOHANG` was specified.

Comment: I read it. I don't want it to get blocked for ever, that's why I did my `while loop`. I want it to check after X seconds or something, and if its still alive, it means termination is failed. If I'll use `waitpid` I won't be able to timeout

Comment: Always check `errno`. `errno` tells you what went wrong. Based on that, take further actions.

Comment: If you kill a process, you have to wait for it. Otherwise you will create a zombie. I thought you want to terminate a process? So, the step after kill is a waitpid. After a kill, what makes you think, that you will wait forever?

Comment: so if we'll sum it up all together: `kill(pid, 0)` and so see if everything is ok. If not, and if `-1` returns, then: `kill(pid, SIGTERM)`. then `waitpid(pid, &status, 0)` and see if the result is `ECHILD`. If no, then `kill(pid, SIGKILL)`. then `waitpid` again and again check if `ECHILD` returns. Did I  get it?

Comment: After a SIGTERM you may want to specify the WNOHANG option (in case the process refuses to terminate). If you specify WNOHANG, in case of no state change, the result of waitpid can be 0 . Remember, ECHILD is set if the process is not a child of the calling process (so further wait is unnecessary). Do not specify WNOHANG after a SIGKILL, in case of an error, it returns immediately, otherwise it blocks until the process has terminated (and will not become a zombie).

Comment: The problem is that the process that should be killed is not always the child.. so `wait` won't help me here.

Comment: That's what i said.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really follow and fully understand your answers. I'll read more about it and read your answers & code again.

Comment: No problem. To make it simple: If it is your child (process), request a termination via SIGTERM. A wait immediately after SIGTERM can give you two different results, either the child complied to your request (in this case, the waitpid returns with the pid of the child) or it blocks until the child terminates. You don't want to block here, so it's best to specify a WNOHANG here. But WNOHANG can give you 0 as a result, that happens if there was no state change of the child (ignored your request).

Comment: But what if its not the child process? Can you edit your answer and write a small piece of code to explain it better than words? And thank you for all your help, of course.

Comment: At this point you have two options, either wait until the child terminates by its own or go straight to a SIGKILL. After a SIGKILL, you **have** to wait for the child (to avoid a zombie process). You would get an error (ECHILD) if the child wouldn't be yours, in any other case waitpid will block until the child process has terminated.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.